# Train Deep Learning model using clean & degraded photos

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have 5000 degraded pictures ( pixelated, blurry, too much luminosity ... ) and their clean versions, and I would like to train a model so that it can predict how to correct future pictures.

I've tried to get as much information as possible, and I think I'll have to train a deep learning model using Tensorflow & Keras, and I'll have to do image inpainting, more precisely a deconvolution method, to get to the expected result.

However, I have strictly no idea about how to get there. I would load both pictures using PIL Image, then convert it into a numpy array, but then I don't really know what to do next.

I do not have any code to show, however I can provide you with a couple pictures. Thanks a lot

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is far too broad and vague, and off topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we are trying to repair degraded images. This task could be performed with the help of [AutoEncoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder).

[image]

The idea is that we could pass the degraded image to the AutoEncoder. The expected ( target ) output will be the *clean* version of the image. Given the degraded image, the AutoEncoder will be trained to generate a *clean* image.

- You can include a number of convolution layers for better feature extraction.
- Use dropout layers, regularization to avoid overfitting. Also, try [Image Data Augmentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-augmentation-for-deep-learning-histogram-equalization-a71387f609b2).

AutoEncoders with images are called Convolutional AutoEncoders. Here are some good blogs to get started,

- [Convolutional Autoencoders](https://pgaleone.eu/neural-networks/2016/11/24/convolutional-autoencoders/)
- [AutoEncoders are Essential in Deep Neural Nets](https://towardsdatascience.com/autoencoders-are-essential-in-deep-neural-nets-f0365b2d1d7c)
- [Colorizing Black & White Faces with Auto-Encoders using TF](https://medium.com/predict/colorizing-black-white-faces-with-auto-encoders-using-tf-7c62d3861f34)